# Finding the diff of two lists of strings

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I'm trying to find a diff (longest common subsequences) between two lists of strings. I'm guessing `difflib` could be useful here, but `difflib.ndiff` annotates the output with `-`, `+`, etc. For instance

```
from difflib import ndiff
t1 = 'one 1\ntwo 2\nthree 3'.splitlines()
t2 = 'one 1\ntwo 29\nthree 3'.splitlines()
d = list(ndiff(t1, t2    )); print d;

['  one 1', '- two 2', '+ two 29', '?      +\n', '  three 3']
```

Is tokenising and removing the letter-codes in the output the right way? Is this the proper Pythonic way of diffing lists?

Comment: If you want an order preserving difference of two lists you can use collections.Counter, get difference between two instances and then build a list elements from first list with positive counter, it can be O(n)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the difference of first list from second, you can convert them to `set` and take set difference using `-` operator.

Example -

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
>>> print(list(set(l1) - set(l2)))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I believe this won't preserve the order and cardinality. I'd like them both preserved though.

Comment: What do your strings really look like?

Comment: @marcus The inputs may look like `['foo', 'bar', 'bar']` and `['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 0):

By List comprehension:

```
In [16]: l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [17]: l2 = ['a', 'x', 'y', 'c']

In [18]: l1_l2 = [ii for ii in l1 if ii not in l2]

In [19]: l1_l2
Out[19]: ['b', 'd']

In [20]: l2_l1 = [ii for ii in l2 if ii not in l1]

In [21]: l2_l1 
Out[21]: ['x', 'y']

In [22]:
```

Comment: The way I understand `difflib` is that it finds the LCS's. I'm not sure list comprehension achieves that. I'll update my question to stress LCS.

Comment: Ok, what is output of this input `['foo', 'bar', 'bar'] and ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz']` ?

Comment: using differ style delta, it'd be something like `['+ foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', '+ baz']`

Comment: I am not getting.. How all values are coming?? any logic so we cam write code

Comment: That should be the standard output from `diff` as we know it. The first instance  of `'foo'` and `'baz`' appear in list2 but not in list1.

Comment: In fact, the output from `list(ndiff(l1, l2))` is `['+ foo', '  foo', '  bar', '  bar', '+ baz']`. I just wonder if that's the proper way of doing it in python, since the manipulating the output strings feels a bit dodgy.

Comment: hmmm.. this is diff code https://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/source/browse/trunk/Lib/difflib.py

Answer (score -2):

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]

l2 = ["a", "b", "d"]
```

If we want to get item which is not there in l2 ("d") try below code

```
l3 = [i for i in l1 if i not in l2]

# l3 now == ["c"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This method will not work for the OP, because the OP is looking for matching substrings, not matching items. So, do both sequences have "a" followed by "b"? Not, do both sequences have "a" and "b"?